# android error on start mainActivity

Tags: android

i have a splashscreen and with Handler i start main Activity, but i give this error in some device:

```
03-06 12:57:40.504  17203-17203/ir.spaad.app.khonak E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-06 12:57:40.554  17203-17203/ir.spaad.app.khonak W/dalvikvm﹕ Refusing to reopen boot DEX '/system/framework/hwframework.jar'
03-06 12:57:40.734  17203-17203/ir.spaad.app.khonak W/System.err﹕ Invalid int: ""
03-06 12:57:41.014  17203-17203/ir.spaad.app.khonak I/Adreno200-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:299>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_2.0.3.04.01.01.21.010_msm8625_JB_REL_2.0.3_Merge_release_AU (Merge)
    Build Date: 10/26/12 Fri
    Local Branch:
    Remote Branch: quic/jb_rel_2.0.3
    Local Patches: NONE
    Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_2.0.3.04.01.01.21.010 +  NOTHING
03-06 12:57:42.244  17203-17203/ir.spaad.app.khonak W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d0b438)
03-06 12:57:42.374  17203-17232/ir.spaad.app.khonak E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1941K, 20% free 11252K/13955K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 45ms
03-06 12:57:42.424  17203-17231/ir.spaad.app.khonak E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1229K, 22% free 10923K/13955K, paused 5ms+2ms, total 30ms
```

my code in splashScreen is:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        startActivity(new Intent(App.context, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
}, 1000);
```

min SDK: 15
targetSdkVersion: 21

Comment: Use App.this in place of App.context.

Comment: Seems you've gotten *No such file or directory* exception and this is irrelevant with that code snippet you've posted. Please explain your problem in more details.

Comment: @SurenderKumar , its not working

Comment: please check your hwframework.jar this file , may be it misplaced or something so please check that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find my problem, in Huiwei device, for enable Logging must past this steps:

1. dial *#*#2846579#*#*
2. select 'ProjectMenu'
3. select 'Background Setting'
4. select 'Log Setting'
5. select 'Log Switch'
6. enable 'LOG on'
7. Select 'Log level setting'
8. enable 'DEBUG'
9. Press the 'Back' key
10. select 'Dump and Log'
11. enable 'Open Dump and Log'
12. Press 'Back' key 5 times to return to home screen.
13. Reboot the phone.

LogCat should now work.